# How to do you implement osano cookieconsent in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js

I am abit stuck on how to implement osano cookie concent javaScript plugin in my nextjs app. So far I have been trying to initialize the cc object in my root landing page useEffect:

```
const CC = require( "CookieConsent")
....

useEffect(() => {
  const cc = new CC({
    container: document.getElementById("cookieconsent"),
    palette: {
    popup: { background: "#1aa3ff" },
    button: { background: "#e0e0e0" },
    },
    revokable: true,
    onStatusChange: function(status) {
    console.log(this.hasConsented() ?
      'enable cookies' : 'disable cookies');
    },
    "position": "bottom-left",
    "theme": "classic",
    "domain": "<myAppURL>",
    "secure": true,
    "content": {
      "header": 'Cookies used on the website!',
      "message": 'This website uses cookies to improve your experience.',
      "dismiss": 'Got it!',
      "allow": 'Allow cookies',
      "deny": 'Decline',
      "link": 'Learn more',
      "href": 'https://www.cookiesandyou.com',
      "close": '&#x274c;',
      "policy": 'Cookie Policy',
      "target": '_blank',
    }
  })
}, [])

return (
...
<div id="cookieconsent"></div>
...
)
....
```

when i do this, i get "ReferenceError: window is not defined" error. Any ideas do I do implement this?

Osano git:
https://github.com/osano/cookieconsent/

Comment: Theres not much documentation how to implement this using the npm module
https://www.osano.com/cookieconsent/documentation/javascript-api/

Answer (score 3):

You should dynamically import "CookieConsent" so it only loads on the client and not on the server. For example:

```
// remove
const CC = require( "CookieConsent")
        
// add
const CC = dynamic(() => import("../node_modules/cookieconsent/src/cookieconsent"), {
  ssr: false
});
```

You'll have to make sure the path to "CookieConsent" from your original require statement is explicitly written, like my dynamic import example.

The window object will then be available, as the window object is only available client side, in the browser, as *the window*.

Take a look at the docs here for reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import